# @Autowired in Spring Boot 3

Tags: spring, spring-boot, annotations, autowired

is @Authowired used in Spring Boot 3 ?
I’m trying to annotate AuthorServiceImpl field in one of my controllers and it doesn’t make any sense because it want’s me to inject the service in controllers constructor.

Comment: `@Autowire` still exists and needs to be in some situations (for example: in tests). When you use `@Component`, `@Service`, and so on when Spring prefers constructor injections. But other frameworks (not just Spring) prefer constructor binding.

Comment: In the constructor, you do not need to use this annotation. Just add normally and Spring will be detected and try to add. Parameter order is not matter. `FooClass(Bar bar, Baz baz) { ... }` If you know some beans maybe not exist, add `@Autowire(required = false)` like: `FooClass(@Autowire(required = false) Bar nullableBar) { ... }`